# avrdude and atmega48pa

Tags: atmega, avrdude, debugging, embedded

Can i programm the atmega48pa with avrdude? I have problems with the signature ...

```
% avrdude -pm48 -cavrisp2 -Pusb -V -U flash:w:main.hex

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e920a
avrdude: Expected signature for ATMEGA48 is 1E 92 05
         Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I have add some new lines to the avrdude.conf in /etc -directory

```
[...]
part
    id               = "m48pa";
    desc             = "ATMEGA48PA";
     has_debugwire = yes;
     flash_instr   = 0xB6, 0x01, 0x11;
     eeprom_instr  = 0xBD, 0xF2, 0xBD, 0xE1, 0xBB, 0xCF, 0xB4, 0x00,
                     0xBE, 0x01, 0xB6, 0x01, 0xBC, 0x00, 0xBB, 0xBF,
                     0x99, 0xF9, 0xBB, 0xAF;
    stk500_devcode   = 0x59;
    signature        = 0x1e 0x92 0x0a;
[...]
```

but now i get a another error

```
avrdude: safemode: Verify error - unable to read lfuse properly. Programmer may not be reliable.
```

---

#### Edit - 1

Here some debugging information with "-vvv":

```
% avrdude -pm48pa -cavrisp2 -Pusb -F -vvv -U flash:w:main.hex

avrdude: Version 5.10, compiled on Apr  3 2010 at 18:48:10
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/silvio/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : avrisp2
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found AVRISP mkII, serno: 000200030996
avrdude: usbdev_open(): using read endpoint 0x82
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): found AVRISP mkII programmer
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA48PA
         Chip Erase delay              : 45000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65     5     4    0 no        256    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6    64    0 yes      4096   64     64  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500V2
         Description     : Atmel AVR ISP mkII
         Programmer Model: AVRISP mkII
         Hardware Version: 1
         Firmware Version Master : 1.10
         Vtarget         : 5.0 V
         SCK period      : 100.37 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e920a
avrdude: safemode read 1, lfuse value: 62
avrdude: safemode read 2, lfuse value: 62
avrdude: safemode read 3, lfuse value: 62
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 62
avrdude: safemode read 1, hfuse value: df
avrdude: safemode read 2, hfuse value: df
avrdude: safemode read 3, hfuse value: df
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DF
avrdude: safemode read 1, efuse value: 1
avrdude: safemode read 2, efuse value: 1
avrdude: safemode read 3, efuse value: 1
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 1
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "main.hex"
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (2336 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 8.54s

avrdude: 2336 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against main.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file main.hex:
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file main.hex contains 2336 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 8.26s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 2336 bytes of flash verified

avrdude: safemode read 1, lfuse value: 62
avrdude: safemode read 2, lfuse value: 62
avrdude: safemode read 3, lfuse value: 62
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 62
avrdude: safemode read 1, hfuse value: df
avrdude: safemode read 2, hfuse value: df
avrdude: safemode read 3, hfuse value: df
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DF
avrdude: safemode read 1, efuse value: 1
avrdude: safemode read 2, efuse value: 1
avrdude: safemode read 3, efuse value: 1
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 1
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

#### Question

Can someone help me to flash a atmega48pa aith a avrispmkii

Comment: Do you still have any problems? According to your final output log, everything worked correctly.

Comment: No I don't have problems anymore ...
Thanks to all for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing:

```
% avrdude -pm48 -cavrisp2 -Pusb -V -U flash:w:main.hex
```

You should be doing:

```
% avrdude -pm48pa -cavrisp2 -Pusb -V -U flash:w:main.hex
```

And in your edit 1 you are using the correct -p flag and it also seems to work. :)

Comment: It's also worth noting that newer versions of avrdude have the newer chip configurations included, so check for updates there too.

Comment: Peter, looking at the latest source in SVN, I cannot find a definition for the m48pa chip (i.e. 0x1e 0x92 0x0A identifier)...

Comment: As a follow-up, adding the new lines to the avrdude config file allowed me to successfully program my ATMEGA48PA (using -p m48pa) firmware and fuses. Thanks silviof!