# Problem shrinking Arduino project to ATtiny 85 20MHz

Tags: arduino, attiny

This is a similar problem as this one: [Programming an ATtiny 85 with Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38284/programming-an-attiny-85-with-arduino)

However the latter question refers to older software/arduino and did not reach a resolution.

I'm using Arduino 1.0.1 (also tried this with 1.0.2) on Mac OS X ML. I've successfully ran the following program on the arduino:

```
int LED_Pin = 3;
int howBright;
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_Pin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  howBright = random(128,255);
  analogWrite(LED_Pin, howBright);
  delay(random(50,150)); 
}
```

Now I have an ATtiny 85 20MHz wired up as instructed here: http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1695

I'm using the hardware for the ATtiny85 here: http://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/downloads/detail?name=arduino-tiny-0100-0015.zip&can=2&q=

I am "uploading with programmer" with "Arduino as ISP" to the ATtiny85 and get this error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Comment: Did you load the ISP sketch into the Arduino?  If you have previously monkeyed with the fuse bits, you may need to slow down the baud rate, or inject a clock (oddly enough, I found I had to inject the clock into the oscout pin rather than the oscin to recover a misfused '85)

Comment: What version ArduinoISP are you using? I remember having to upgrade the standard supplied version. I use version 04m3

Comment: I wrote the code and loaded it to the Arduino, yes. It's working directly off the Arduino. I don't know what fuse bits are, but I don't think I monkeyed with them. I also don't know what injecting clocks means or what oscout pins are. Sorry, I'm a web developer still learning electronics.

Comment: @jippie I assume that's different than Arduino.app? How do I check or change the version?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz it is at the top of the source code, which you loaded from the Arduino GUI to program the Arduino. First line: `// ArduinoISP version 04m3` One or two lines below that is a link to the Google code repositories.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz - to program a different chip with an Arduino, you have to load the ISP sketch into the Arduino, not the program which you are trying to run.  Once you have the ISP sketch in the Arduino, you can change the programmer in the menu to that, and use it to load your ultimate program into the target chip.

Comment: Voting to close - question has been long abandoned with no followup from the poster that could lead to resolution, and there seems to be little of general value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to confirm your steps with http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP and https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/200 to be sure.
It seems you didn't upload Arduino ISP code to your Arduino first. Plug your Arduino to your computer and upload ArduinoISP from Examples menu. Then you may retry to program your Attiny by selecting "Arduino as ISP" from Tools | Programmer menu.

Comment: This is a very common and easily overlooked mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking to make sure your Arduino is working as an ISP programmer correctly, first. You could try to use it to program another Arduino or ATMega or even an ATTiny which you know to be working, with a very simple piece of code. Perhaps even use just use avrdude's terminal to see if the ISP is able to make a connection with a regular target.

You could also attempt to program your ATTiny with another ISP programmer that you know to be working. This should let you confirm that you don't have incorrect fuses on the ATtiny which is making it unresponsive.

You will have to reduce the problem space by trying to zero in on where the actual problem is if someone here is going to be able to help you. Knowing what the precise problem is and the exact symptoms (beyond "something is not working", which is really all the stk500 error message tells us) can make a world of difference when you're troubleshooting. The smaller the problem space, the more likely a solution can be found.